# Creating Tile map interactivity in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a map interactivity which will consume huge image (about 7000 x 7000px) which will be in zoomed out state. User can zoom inside the map and click on his point of interest.
I need this to create using HTML5 and Javasctipt, jQuery etc. I do not want to use any google map APIs to create this. The map will be hand-drawn and could be in image format.

I am not sure about what technique can be applied to get the result like google map.

A bit of guidance will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I found **Open Layers** is the technique which can be used to solve the above problem but with custom image.

Interestingly I got a tool which cuts huge image into several tiles and outputs content in Open Layers.

**MapTiler**: http://www.maptiler.org/

This is wonderful software and absolutely free.

Thanks, hope this is helpful to others :)